# Torque's lever arm to attain specific accel of center of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque

I have trouble with the following exersice.

[image]

A disc of mass $M$ and radius $R$ rolls without slipping.

$F=10N$

$M=5kg$

$I=MR^2/2$

$a_{cm}=2,5 m/s^2$
[image]

So, I tried the following:

$$\sum F_x = F-F_\mu$$
$$\tau=F·sin(\theta)R+F_\mu·R$$
Get an expression for $F_\mu$
$$a_{cm}=\frac{\sum F_x}{M}=\frac{F-F_\mu}{M} \Rightarrow F_\mu=-a_{cm}M+F$$ 
Then substitute in the torque equation:
$$\tau=F·sin(\theta)R+(-a_{cm}M+F)·R $$
$$\tau= R(F·sin(\theta)-a_{cm}M+F)$$
Now, get angular acceleration from torque:
$$\alpha = \frac{\tau}{I} = \frac{2R}{MR^2}(F·sin(\theta)-a_{cm}M+F)$$
$$\alpha =  \frac{2}{MR}(F·sin(\theta)-a_{cm}M+F)$$
Now get tangencial acceleration:
$$a_t=\alpha R$$
$$a_t= \frac{2}{M}(F·sin(\theta)-a_{cm}M+F)$$
Equate to $a_{cm}$
$$a_{cm}=a_t/2$$
$$a_{cm}=\frac{F·sin(\theta)-a_{cm}M+F}{M}$$
Now solve for $sin(\theta)=h/R$
$$2a_{cm}=\frac{F·sin(\theta)+F}{M}$$
$$\frac{2a_{cm}M}{F}-1 = sin(\theta) = h/R$$
$$h=(\frac{2a_{cm}M}{F}-1)R = (\frac{(2)(2,5)(5)}{10}-1)R$$
$$h=1,5R$$

And that is obviously wrong.

Where is the mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler approach is to consider the moment of inertia about the "instantaneous point of rotation" - namely the edge of the disk.

From the parallel axes theorem, the moment of inertia about this point (distance $R$ from the center of mass) is

$$I_e = I_c + MR^2 = \frac32 M R^2$$

Now you want a linear acceleration of $a$, which implies an angular acceleration of $\dot\omega = \frac{a}{R}$.

Finally, the torque applied is $\Gamma = F\cdot(R+h)$.

The equation of motion is

$$\Gamma = I_e \dot\omega$$

Substitute the expressions for each of the three terms, and solve for $h$. I think you will find it a faster approach. You are making life harder for yourself by trying to carry $\theta$ forward in the equations, when the torque can be found directly (this is possible because there is no slip...).

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering! I will try that.

Comment: Note that "check my work" questions are off topic, and site policy discourages "complete" answers to homework questions. But since you have shown significant effort, I thought giving you a good pointer (but leaving you to do the details) was probably the right approach. Let me know if you can now get the "right" answer...!

Comment: Yes, I got to the right answer. That was incredibly helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: Another question? Is it right if I continue to post homework questions in this way, or was this answer some kind of exception? I'm not trying to break the site's rules here

Comment: "where is the mistake" is typically the wrong question to ask. However, if you show good intent (as you did) and ask a conceptual question (in this case you didn't... but something like "my approach to calculating the torque is giving me a physically impossible answer. What is the right way to determine the torque here?" will, on a good day, get a favorable response. And when you get a helpful response, you can choose to "accept" it (with the little check mark below the score). This indicates that you feel your question has been answered, and "thanks" the person who wrote the answer.